# React js Pass data from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont know why I cant pass the value that i set on may parent component to child component, ofcourse there is nothing wrong with getting or fetching the record, is there any wrong with my code?

```
import ChildComponent from "../components/Forms/ChildComponent";

const [showchild, setchild] = useState(false);
const [getData, setData] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
   ...
   setchild(true)
   setData(data) //the data is from my database and it has a record
   ...
})

return(

    {showchild ? (
      <>
        <ChildComponent getData={getData}></ChildComponent>
      </>
    )}
)
```

ChildComponent.js

```
export default function ChildComponent(getData) {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("get Data from Parent component: ", getData) // I dont know why I cant pass the value that i set on may parent component to child component,
  
  })

}
.....,
```

Comment: `ChildComponent({ getData })`. You forgot to destructure the `props` object.

Comment: You should probably also add an empty dependency array on your effect too if you want to add that data to state only when the component is mounted. And i'd probably call it `data` rather than `getData` - it's a thing, not an action. Same with `showChild` - just call it `child`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `getData` value using following way:

**Solution 1**

```
export default function ChildComponent({getData}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("get Data from Parent component: ", getData) 
  })

}
```

**Solution 2**

```
export default function ChildComponent(props) {

  const { getData } = props 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("get Data from Parent component: ", getData) 
  })

}
```